# How to turn off new popup for spell checking in Word for Mac on macOS 11.3

Tags: macos, ms-office, spellcheck

After the last macOS update, a popup started appearing when you click on a misspelled word in Word for Mac.
[image: Popup for helping with spelling in Word for Mac]

This is a very frustrating function when you work in several different languages not always wanting to spell-check even though the red underscoring is good as a reminder. Hence, I want to keep the previous functionality to get suggestions when right-clicking on an underscored word but would really want to turn this popup function off. Does anyone know how this could be done?

The only option I've found is to turn spell-checking as you write off completely, which also removes the red underscoring that I'd like to keep.

Comment: Latest macOS and latest Word. Don't observe described behavior. However, something does happen while using online Word i.e. in browser ('Click to view suggestions' -> popup window somewhat similar, but has 'Editor' as well)

Comment: I can confirm that this does appear but not in every word version (possibly MS is a/b testing?). I have this on my personal mac but not on my work one, but I can't figure out why since they are both on the same office account (preview builds are not enabled)

Comment: I don't have an answer, but am seeing the same thing. Doesn't happen on my work laptop but does happen on my personal desktop. Both OS and Office are latest versions. Frustrating!

Comment: I have the same problem. This is incredibly annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to preferences > View and untick comments on rollover [image]

Answer (score 0):

Just experienced this and I found the solution.

On Mac, goto

```
Word -> Preferences-> AutoCorrect (make sure you're on the AutoCorrect tab)
```

and at the bottom un-check `Automatically use suggestions from the spelling checker` and this will remove that annoying new pop-up bubble.

However, the red squiggly lines will still be there and you can still right-click and see your options to fix the red squiggly lines (just like how it used to be before this update).

Comment: Sadly, did this not work for me. Unchecked the box you suggested and even restarted Word, but the annoying pop-up bubble that literally drives me nuts are still there...

Answer (score 0):

Deselecting this worked for the spelling suggestions box, but not grammar (I still get those popups...)

[image]