# Turn off new popup for spell checking in MS Word for Mac on macOS 10.15

Tags: macos, spellcheck

After my last macOS update, a popup started appearing when you click/hover on a misspelled word in MS Word for Mac.

[image]

This is very frustrating when you are working with randomly generated IDs.

I've tried [Tom T Thumb's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/419624/how-to-turn-off-new-popup-for-spell-checking-in-word-for-mac-on-macos-11-3) but that did not work for me.

The only other option is to turn spell-checking off complete, however it removes the red underscoring which I still need.

Any help would be appreciated - thanks!!

Comment: How is this question different from the one you link to? Consider deleting this question as it is a duplicate.